# Lua metamethod __newindex: "this event happens when table is not a table"?

Tags: lua

The Lua 5.3 Reference Manual (in this [part](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4), scroll down) says:

> __newindex: The indexing assignment table[key] = value. Like the index event, this event happens when table is not a table or when key is not present in table. The metamethod is looked up in table.

However I don't understand that the metamethod __newindex happens when table is not a table. What does that mean? I did try to re-assign a local with `nil`, but it didn't work (yes, I know it doesn't make sense to re-assign the table, but this would help it to be garbage-collected).

```
local v = {};

setmetatable(v, {
    __newindex = function(t,k,v)
        print("Aaahhh...!");
    end
});

v = nil;
```

I'm using this [online compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/try_lua.php) to test it.

Comment: In addition to the current answer, it should be noted you can set the meta table for other values as well. ```setmetatable``` can set it of a table or user data. ```debug.setmetatable``` can set a single metatable that will apply to every value of different data types.

Comment: Which is what it means by not a table :)

Comment: @warspy This means that every type of value on Lua is a object? Thanks for the help! With help of both of your comment and smarx's answer I understand it now. This should be really noted on the answer

Comment: No, not all values are objects! Not at all. If you set the metatable of 1 for example, ALL numbers will have that datatype. Only tables and userdata are objects.

Comment: @warspyking I see, so that's easy! I compiled a code of what you said in action... http://ideone.com/Nu8a1W it's just like a prototype...

Comment: Nope, they're just like what they are. Not objects, not protypes. The debug library breaks a lot if rules in Lua, non objects having metatables being one of them. You *shouldn't* use it.

Comment: @warspyking Yeah, I know they're not prototypes, but they look like. I'd not use this kind of metatable, too, but I should implement it on a transpiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the page you cited:

> You can replace the metatable of tables using the setmetatable
>   function. You cannot change the metatable of other types from Lua code
>   (except by using the debug library (§6.10)); you should use the C API
>   for that.

You can't use `setmetatable` to change the metatable for something that's not a table, so you won't be able to verify what you expect (that the `__newindex` method is called when you index into something that's not a table).

Your code runs because you *are* setting the metatable for a table. (`local v = {}` creates a table.)

But reassigning the variable `v` to be something else means you no longer have a way to get to the table you created. If your last line were `v[5] = 'Hello'`, then you would see that your metamethod is invoked.

**EDIT**

Reading your edit, it looks like you expected `__newindex` to get called when the table was garbage collected? I think you misunderstood the statement that `__newindex` is called "when table is not a table." That means if you did something like this:

```
local v = 5
print(v[3]) -- indexing into something that's not a table
```

`__newindex` would be called (because in the expression `table[key]`, which here is `v[3]`, `table` is not a table). But you can't actually set up `__newindex` via the `setmetatable` method, because that method only works on tables.

Comment: This is helpful, I always thought that it were impossible to set metatable for other value types since I started learning the metatables, but why does Lua accepts that metamethod __newindex for other value types?

Comment: Lua has a large focus on embedding use-cases, so I suspect the flexibility here is to make sure that when embedding Lua via the C interface, you can create table-like things (supporting indexing) that aren't actually Lua tables.